# How to combine 3 canvas HTML elements into 1 image file using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I have 3 canvas i.e. canvasTarget, canvasTarget2, canvasTarget3 as shown below:

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasTarget");
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvasTarget2");
        var img2 = canvas2.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        var canvas3 = document.getElementById("canvasTarget3");
        var img3 = canvas3.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
```

I want to combine these canvas elements into one and download as JPEG or PDF file.
I am using /html2canvas.js for downloading this.
Any immediate response will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Add HTML and populate canvas with some example images. As it stands, we have very little to go on. Also, in what way do you want to combine them? Will this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787899/combining-two-or-more-canvas-elements-with-some-sort-of-blending ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So you've rendered your canvases, but it's not clear how you want to combine them - overlaid, side-by-side?  In either case you can use `Canvas.context.drawImage()` to add them to a new canvas object, and then use the `Canvas.toDataURL()` method to return the, erm, dataURL of the new canvas.

Something like this perhaps...

```
/* assumes each canvas has the same dimensions */
var overlayCanvases = function(cnv1, cnv2, cnv3) {
    var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d'),
        width = cnv1.width,
        height = cnv1.height;

    newCanvas.width = width;
    newCanvas.height = height;

    [cnv1, cnv2, cnv3].forEach(function(n) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.drawImage(n, 0, 0, width, height);
    });

    return newCanvas.toDataURL();
};

/* assumes each canvas has the same width */
var verticalCanvases = function(cnv1, cnv2, cnv3) {
    var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d'),
        width = cnv1.width,
        height = cnv1.height + cnv2.height + cnv3.height;

    newCanvas.width = width;
    newCanvas.height = height;

    [{
        cnv: cnv1,
        y: 0
    },
    {
        cnv: cnv2,
        y: cnv1.height
    },
    {
        cnv: cnv3,
        y: cnv1.height + cnv2.height
    }].forEach(function(n) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.drawImage(n.cnv, 0, n.y, width, n.cnv.height);
    });

    return newCanvas.toDataURL();
};

/* USAGE */
var dURL1 = overlayCanvases(canvas1,canvas2,canvas3);
var dURL2 = verticalCanvases(canvas1,canvas2,canvas3);
```

The `overlayCanvases()` function will place the canvases on top of each other, so the order of the arguments is important.  The `verticalCanvases()` will align the canvas vertically and in descending order.  The important thing to notice here is that `Canvas.context.drawImage()` allows you to paint one canvas into another - relative positioning can be jiggled to suit your purposes.

Functions above Fiddled : https://jsfiddle.net/BnPck/cyLrmpjy/

Comment: Chuckle, great minds think alike... :-) But you do need to allow for adequate width for the widest of the 3 canvases. ;-)

Comment: @markE.  Yeah, but the question was a little on the vague side eh?  ;-)

Comment: Yep, I almost voted the question as "unclear", but they likely mean either of 2 things: 1-overlay all canvases or 2-stack all canvases so the question is unclear but self-scoping.

Comment: @Mark & Brian: Apologies for not making it clear. My intention is to take download a screenshot of my aspx page. I am having multiple canvas elements in the page and i want to combine all (side by side, not overlay) into one and download it.

Comment: @MrutyunjayaMohapatra. Fair enough ... both answers will combine 3 canvases into a single canvas for export. :-)

Comment: @BrianPeacock Are the lines `ctx.beginPath();` neccessary?

Comment: @John Not strictly necessarily with the `canvasContext.drawImage` function on its own, but it's a good habit generally that doesn't cost much. ;)