# I have 2 canvas which are layered. Can i bind it together and save it using blob?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

[Here's the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqDJd.png)
The first canvas is the tshirt and the second one is layered on top of the shirt. I need to save the design only and the one with the tshirt. Can i bind the two canvas? I am using Blob to save the design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining two or more Canvas elements with some sort of blending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787899/combining-two-or-more-canvas-elements-with-some-sort-of-blending)

Comment: Just draw the top canvas on to the other one `ctx.drawImage(topCanvas,0,0);` then save the composite result.

Comment: @Blindman67 will this work only with onload? Because the canvas i am dealing with is dynamic. Sorry i am new to this.