# How do I use Pixastic?

Tags: jquery, pixastic

I'm trying to blend two images using the [Pixastic plugin](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blend/) - here's [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/tara_irvine/vQLSH/20/).

These images will be dynamic, I'm not really sure why the test isn't working. Chances are I've done something wrong as I don't think I've coded it correctly. Does this have to be working with the jQuery plugin?

Can someone please explain how to get the blending mode working on 2 images, one of which is unknown but the IDs are fixed?

Comment: What is the demo supposed to do?

Comment: Looks like it is working to me - the "worry lines" are superimposed on the model's forehead.

Comment: neither of those files (blend, pixastic) reference jquery in them, so no they're not dependent on jquery

Comment: Thanks guys, the forehead "worry lines" are meant to blend into the picture of the model. Like this http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blend/ I keep getting this error "Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 "

Comment: Don't you think it would have been a good idea to put the error message in the question in the first place? Anyway, the error means that you're being bitten by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which puts limitations to what you can do with the data. Put all the pictures to the same server where the script is and you should be good.

Comment: Sorry it was on the Jsfiddle so I thought everyone could see it. I understand, so in order to test, everything needs to be on the same sever. I'll update it now. Thanks

Comment: I ended up using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648312/blend-two-images-on-a-javascript-canvas/3648399#3648399 I couldn't get Pixastic to work so I built my own, thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

1. Your second images loaded is retrieving a 404. It means there is any image there.
2. Your External libraries (pixastic.core.js, blend.js) are retrieving a 404 status too.
3. You must get the image element on the second line of your javascript.

   var img = new Image();
   img = document.getElementById("userImage");