# Add hue to a regular image with CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I have a regular image in the image tag like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCRMm.jpg):

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCRMm.jpg" class="image">
```

that I want to turn into this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSHQt.png). I saw some examples of the blend mode but for the blend mode you need to set the image as background but I have the image in the image tag.

Can the hue be added to the image via css without setting image as background?

Comment: yes, you can achieve that kind of effect using `CSS` only.

Answer (score 5):

Use a parent to your image with the desired background color.
Than set `mix-blend-mode: overlay;` to your image

```css
img{max-width:100%;vertical-align:top;}


.blend-overlay{ mix-blend-mode: overlay; }
```

```html
<div style="background:#822;">
   <img class="blend-overlay" src="https://i.imgur.com/StEW4JD.jpg">
</div>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31528825/383904

Comment: Note that mix-blend-mode is not supported in all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode

Answer (score 2):

you looking this type image.
Demo link here https://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/9v96yfro/

HTML

```
<div class="image-box">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/StEW4JD.jpg" class="image">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image-box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.image:after {
    content: "";
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you are using the __.image__ class 2 two times here which might cause an issue with existing code.

Comment: OK now fine i had change class

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use css filter (on image) and css-pseudo element as overlay. But that (filter) won't work on older IE tho...

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
          filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.image-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/StEW4JD.jpg" class="image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## I'll suggest using [CSS Filter](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/)

its Browser Support is pretty good with -webkit- prefix besides IE < 12.

https://jsfiddle.net/9v96yfro/2/

```
.image {
  filter: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(300deg) brightness(75%) saturate(200%);
}
```

Quick recap on what it does:
Its colorizes the image by applying a sepia effect to the image taking all color information out of the image and changing the hue of the color by 300deg to a reddish kinda color. Saturation and brightness is set to match your example image.

Play around with the values and adjust them to your liking.
You can read more about [CSS Filter at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter)